# How to pass in a parameter from XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm making an experiment with `express` and `XHR`. And I came up with a problem that after passing a params in `xhr.send(params)` didn't recieve it on the `app.post()`. I don't know if my code is correct but here it is.

My `app.js` file:

```
app.post('/', urlencodedParser, async (req, res) => {
    console.log('Received a request!', req.body); // I also tried req.params, req.query and still the same
    // output: "Recieved a request! {}"
    res.end('respond!');
});
```

Here's my `script.js` file:

```
xhr.open('POST', '/', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
            name: 'SomeName'
        }));
```

Why is it that the params is empty when I recivied it in the `app.js`? Is this how you really pass in parameters?

Comment: Do you have `app.use(express.json())` middleware before your `app.post()` route?  If not, you need that before `req.body` will have the data from the POST in it.

Comment: Also, why are you setting `xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');` when you're getting back text, not json?

Comment: I didn't know it is as simple as that, and it actually worked

Answer (score 0):

You need this:

```
app.use(express.json())
```

somewhere before your `app.post()` handler.  That middleware will read the body of the response and parse the JSON and put the resulting Javascript properties into the `req.body` object for your later request handler to examine.

If you don't have that middleware, then the body of the POST is never read and thus `req.body` is never populated.

Comment: @JamesUrian - If this answered your question, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.